# Distance and metrics between datasets

Tags: dataset, artificial-intelligence, distance, hierarchy

I have almost 30 different data-sets. Each of them contain a different number of variables and the dimension is around 46.

I'm trying to measure the distance between these data-sets, rather than the distance between the items within each data set themselves. My proposal is to find the mean for each data-set and the to use euclidean or mahalanobis distance to find the linkage and build my structure.

I already know the number of clusters, as it is defined by the number of data sets. I just need to find the distance between my data sets.

Is the way I'm doing this good enough or should I find a metric other than the average which better represents each data set? Do these distance functions fit the measurement or not? Is it necessary to do any normalization or dissimilarity calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not looking at distances of the means of your data-sets is good enough depends entirely on your data-sets. In general, the mean is **sensitive to outliers**. This means that if your data-sets have a few values that are wildly different than the others, they will have a notable effect on the mean (i.e. they will pull it towards them). This might be desired behavior, but usually it's not. So, if the values that your taking the mean of are all fairly similar, mean is a good option.

Here are some other options:

**Single-link** - The distance between two clusters is the distance between the points in the two clusters that are closest to each other. This is useful if you care about "best-case" proximity, i.e. how similar the data-sets could possibly be.

[image: An illustration of single-link distance.]

**Complete-link** - The distance between two clusters is the distance between the points in the two clusters that are farthest from each other. This is useful if you care about "worst-case" proximity, i.e. how dissimilar the data-sets could possibly be.

[image: An illustration of complete-link distance]

Images from [this website](http://www-m9.ma.tum.de/material/felix-klein/clustering/Methoden/Hierarchisches_Clustern_Beispiel.php).

Another potentially relevant consideration is that calculating the mean can generally be performed faster than single-link or complete-link.

There are more complicated distance metrics that you could use if it's important to capture information about the amount of variation within your data-sets. For instance, you could measure distance in standard deviations (although this gets tricky because different data-sets will have different standard deviations).

Comment: I do care more about the dissimilarity between my data sets. could you point me more to the std distance plz ?

Comment: Sure! Take a look at Bhattacharyya distance (of which Mahalanobis distance is a special case) and total variation distance.

Comment: Dear @seaotternerd, might I know if the means are not equal between the classes, Can we still apply the Bhattacharyya distance ?

Comment: Yes, you can absolutely apply Bhattacharyya distance if the means are not equal. There are very few distance algorithms for which unequal means are a problem (in most cases that is the only way to get a non-zero distance).

Comment: Did you possibly mean that the standard deviations are unequal? That is a question on which there is a lot more variation among distance metrics. Bhattacharyya distance can handle unequal standard deviations, but many other distance metrics, such as Mahalanobis distance, cannot. This is one of the key benefits of Bhattacharyya distance.

Comment: Yes the mean is not equal and variation also, I'm using the euclidean distance but I don't think it gives a right divergence, I have several classes with high dimensions. I'm thinking of using another distance function using the variance also to measure the distance. I tried by the Mahalanobis but it gave me error cause of the variance.

Comment: using the Bhattacharyya distance require the Matrix to be positive definite which I don't know how to solve this issue, by using the NPD it require using square matrix.